# app is crashing when i'am using checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-studio, checkbox

I'm trying to make a app in android studio(java) but i have a little problem whit my checkbox. every time when I unchecked the checkbox my app will crash. it is the intention that when a checkbox is checked, the integer is stored in a arraylist and a randomizer pick one of those integers out of the array and displays it. can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong.

.java file

```
    package com.developer.sven.dartworkout20;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PreferenceDartThrow extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preference_dart_throw_page);

    Intent preferenceDartThrowPageOpened = getIntent();
    String previousActivity = preferenceDartThrowPageOpened.getExtras().getString("Pref");
}

ArrayList<Integer> selection = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void selectNumber(View view) {
    boolean numberChecked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.number_D1:
            if (numberChecked) {
                selection.add(1);
            } else {
                selection.remove(1);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.number_D2:
            if (numberChecked) {
                selection.add(2);
            } else {
                selection.remove(2);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.number_D3:
            if (numberChecked) {
                selection.add(3);
            } else {
                selection.remove(3);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.number_D4:
            if (numberChecked) {
                selection.add(4);
            } else {
                selection.remove(4);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.number_D5:
            if (numberChecked) {
                selection.add(5);
            } else {
                selection.remove(5);
            }
            break;
  }
}
}
```

.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/number_D1"
        android:onClick="selectNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_double"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false" />


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/number_D2"
        android:onClick="selectNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number_D1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/number_D3"
        android:onClick="selectNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number_D2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/number_D4"
        android:onClick="selectNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number_D3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:onClick="selectNumber"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number_D4"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/number_D5"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

error log

```
02-27 14:15:33.540 1024-1024/com.developer.sven.dartworkout20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.developer.sven.dartworkout20, PID: 1024
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                                    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
                                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
                                                                                    at com.developer.sven.dartworkout20.PreferenceDartThrow.selectNumber(PreferenceDartThrow.java:38)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                                                                                    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use remove(1),, you are removing the entry at position "1", not the entry with value "1". If you want to remove entry with value "1", you have to convert to an object first:

```
selection.remove(new Integer(1));
```

Comment: You can also also use a String ArrayList to add your items and then, you can parse them into integer, when ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use String ArrayList and remove the item that you want to remove directly.
If you have a constraint to use Integer only you can convert that int into string and revert back by parsing using

```
Integer.parseInt(str)
```

when ever needed. Using String list to add and remove List Items for a CheckBox is demonstrated in this video. https://youtu.be/1H5-CBQWS-o
Do checkout
Hope that helps you with your question.